# Replace character in a dataframe with another character

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, string-substitution

I want to change the character "F" to "X" in a dataframe.
Please see below.

```
df <- data.frame(N=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),CAT=c('A','B','C','D','E','F'))
df

Result:
      N CAT
    1 1   A
    2 2   B
    3 3   C
    4 4   D
    5 5   E
    6 6   F
```

I've run this code and it doesn't work

```
    df$CAT[df$CAT == 'F'] <- 'X'

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, code, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
```

This code seems to work on other data I've imported via csv. Is there a reason why it doesn't work with this specific dataframe I've created? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It is working for me though  Please check whether there are leading/lagging spaces for 'CAT'

Comment: That works for me as well. Are you sure the error occurs when you copy/paste the code you've shared?

Comment: @akrun - there are times when i'm running code and isn't doing things as it should. This arose because i saw your previous solution to a problem. The guy was happy but when i tried to run it myself, it didn't work. Do i need to re-install R? Can R become corrupted or outdated? I've been loading a lot of packages recently, could that effect R?

Comment: I don't save the session when I close the session.  If you are saving the session on global env, it could pollute the env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the proverbial `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. For those reading it after R4.0 it is no longer a problem, but for many years before 2020 users struggled remembering that `data.frame` (and `as.data.frame()` for that matter) automatically coerces all strings to factors.

What then happens is that you are trying to introduce new levels into a factor and this is not how it needs to be done in R. If creation of factor was not an intention, you could just modify your data frame creation code.

```r
df <- data.frame(N=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 CAT=c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you, however, wanted to create a factor, here's how you can go about modifying the levels and recoding one of the levels.

```r
df <- data.frame(N=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 CAT=c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
df
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
#> $ N  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6
#> $ CAT: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6

levels(df$CAT)[levels(df$CAT)=="F"] <- "X"

df

#> N CAT
#> 1 1   A
#> 2 2   B
#> 3 3   C
#> 4 4   D
#> 5 5   E
#> 6 6   X
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks @dmi3kno. I remember this being an issue which put me off using R in the past. I will download the latest R.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the recode function from dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(N=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),CAT=c('A','B','C','D','E','F'))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(CAT = recode(CAT, 'F'= 'X'))

df
```